# Include 2 namespaces in razorview?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to Include 2 NameSpaces means 2 ViewModel to my Razor View `AddViewModel` and `updateVIewModel`.

Currently I am Using One View Model Like:

```
/* NameSpace Name */
@model Web.Models.SettingViewModel;
```

I want to add:

```
@model Web.Models.UpdateSettingViewModel
```

How to do this ??

Answer (score 1):

You can pass to the `view` a [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx)

```
  //create the instances
  SettingViewModel svm = new SettingViewModel();
  UpdateSettingViewModel usv = new UpdateSettingViewModel();

  //create the Tuple
  var tpl = new Tuple<SettingViewModel, UpdateSettingViewModel>(svm,usv);

  //pass the Tuple to the view
  return View(tpl);

  //get the values
  var a = tpl.Item1;
  var b = tpl.Item2;
```

or a [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264741.aspx)

```
  //Create a dynamic object
  dynamic dn = new { SettingViewModel = svm, UpdateSettingViewModel = usv };

  //pass the dynamic to the view
  return View(dn);

  //get the values in the view
  var dn1 = dn.SettingViewModel;
  var dn2 = dn.UpdateSettingViewModel;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a viewmodel that has these two viemodels as its properties. Currently you cannot pass two or more viewmodels to the razor view.